# A Combinatorics question whose solution I can't understand.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The question is

"For a natural number $n$, let $T(n)$ denote the number of ways we can place $n$ objects of weights $1,2,...,n$ on a balance such that the sum of the weights in each pan is the same. Prove that $T(100) > T(99)$."

Now while I have (one of the many possible) solutions thanks to the fact that the people conducting this test released it, though I do not understand one bit of it.

Could someone explain me how to do this question? It's very difficult (for students) as it's part of the Stage I of selection of students from India for the International Mathematics Olympiad.

I am so confused even looking at the question!!!

The solution which was posted was: (scroll down to the last question) http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/crmo-2013-solutions-2

I apologize in advance if this is too simple to search on the Internet.

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to find a $1$ to $1$ injection from balanced partitions with $99$ items to balanced partitions with $100$ items.

For example, replace item $50$ with item $100$ and put item $50$ in the other part: both parts have increased by $50$ so are still balanced

Then to show a strict inequality, find another balanced partition  with $100$ items not already seen, i.e. with items $50$ and $100$ on the same side.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is

> Let $\mathcal S(n)$ denote the collection of subsets $A$ of $X(n) = \{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ such that the sum of the elements of $A$ equals $n(n+1)/4$.

This means that $X(n)$ is the set that contains the numbers from 1 up to $n$, which you are trying to divide into two parts, so that the sum of the numbers in one part is equal to the sum of the numbers in the other part.

Since the sum of all the numbers $1+2+\cdots n$ is equal to $ \frac12n(n+1)$, when the numbers are divided into two parts with equal sums, the two parts each have a sum of $\frac14n(n+1)$.

$S(n)$ is a family sets, each of which contains some of the numbers from $1$ to $n$. A set, say $A$, is a member of the family $S(n)$, if the sum of its elements is $\frac14n(n+1)$.

Do you understand the first sentence now? If not, what part don't you understand?

Comment: So $S(n)$ is basically a power set of $X(n)$ including only those sets whose elements add up to $n(n+1)/4$?

Comment: Yes, except that $\mathcal S(n)$ is a *subset* of the power set of $X(n)$. It doesn't contain *every* subset of $X(n)$; it contains only the subsets whose elements add up to $\frac14n(n+1)$.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for the really quick replies. I don't understand the rest of the solution as well.

Comment: Now you should re-read the second sentence and see if you understand it better.

Comment: I don't understand what is giving a map $f : S(99) \to S(100)$ (a function? If yes, why do we do it, what does it really mean?)

Comment: That's the third sentence. Do you understand the second sentence?

Comment: The second one is obvious(once someone gets the first one). I understand it. I am having  a doubt in 3rd one.

Answer (score 1):

You said you now understand the first two sentences.

The third sentence is

> We shall give a map $f : \mathcal S(99) \to \mathcal S(100)$ that is one-to one but not onto.

A map is a function.  A function $f : A \to B$ takes an element from set $A$ and gives you back an element of set $B$.  There is a theorem that says that if there is a function $f : A\to B$ that is one-to-one but not onto, then set $A$ has fewer elements than set $B$.

To see this, consider the range $f[A]$ of the function.  This is a subset of $B$. Because $f[A]$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $A$, it is the same size as $A$.  But because $f$ is not onto $B$ (that is, there are elements of $B$ that are not in the range of $f$) then $f[A]$ is a proper subset of $B$.  So $A$ is the same size as a proper subset of $B$, so must have fewer elements than $B$.

If we could construct a function $f : \mathcal S(99) \to \mathcal S(100)$ that was one-to-one but not onto, we would have shown that $\mathcal S(99)$ was smaller than $\mathcal S(100)$, which , according to sentence 2  (which you say you understand) would solve the problem.

Comment: GREAT! I understood this and why we did this. Now how to prove that $f : S(99) \to S(100)$ is one-to-one and not onto (I don't understand the steps given in the solution). Thanks a lot.

Comment: The next three sentences (“Suppose that $A$ is … $f(A) = A\cup\{50\}$. ) define the function $f$ that the solution uses. Do you understand how the function $f$ works?

Comment: Use `A\setminus\{50\}` to write $A\setminus\{50\}$.  $A\setminus \{50\}$ is a set that has everything that $A$ has, except $50$.

Comment: $A\setminus \{50\}$ is a set that has everything that $A$ has, except $50$.

Comment: OK, so why do we define it this way? Especially the union with 100?

Comment: Because it works.  We want that if $a\in \mathcal S(99)$ (that is, if $a$'s elements add up to 2475), then $f(a)\in \mathcal S(100)$ (that is, $f(a)$'s elements should add up to 2525). We want $f$ to be one-to-one, and we want $f$ to be not onto. If we can do that, we win.  This definition of $f$ does those things.

Comment: In particular, if you want $f$ to be a function from $\mathcal S(99)$ to $\mathcal S(100)$, it must take a set $x$ whose sum is 2475 and return a set whose sum is 2525. If the set doesn't already contain $50$, you can do that by returning $x\cup\{50\}$, and if $x$ already contains $50$, you can do that by returning $x\setminus\{50\}\cup\{100\}$.

Comment: OK, your second comment made it MUCH clearer. So, as I see it, we choose the condition of $50 \in A$ (when $A \in S(99)$) because the sums required (2475 and 2525) differ by 50, making it easier when $50 \not \in S(99)$. When 50 is there, we can avoid 50, but then we need 100 and fortunately 100 won't be in any set in $S(99)$. So we can just unite the $A\setminus\{50\}
$ with {100}. Am I correct?

Comment: I would be thankful if you could explain a bit more of the solution and tell me if my above comment is true.

Comment: You are correct.  Now your job is to show that this function from $\mathcal S(99)$ to $\mathcal S(100)$ is one-to-one but not onto. If you can do that, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Now I am sorry, but despite everything, I don't understand the NEXT two sentences where they prove that the function is one-to-one. Could you please explain that. I also do not understand the "not onto" proof. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you don't understand their proof, perhaps you can write your own proof?

Comment: Since I don't have enough knowledge to write a proof on my own, I carefully looked at their proof. So, they say that if A and B are two sets belonging to S(99), and $f(A)=f(B)$, then 50 belongs to both of them or neither of them, because our function is defined that way. Now if 50 belongs to both of them, $f(A) = A\setminus\{50\}\cup\{100\} = f(B) = B\setminus\{50\}\cup\{100\}$. Is it correct that this can be the case ONLY IF $A = B$, I got the one-to-one proof. Is it correct?

Comment: Could you explain the not onto proof if my assumption in my above comment is valid?

Comment: I think we have taken this as far as it can go in the comments.  Perhaps we could continue the discussion in email.  My address is on my profile page.

Comment: Can I move this discussion to chat? Also, I don't think email addresses are visible to others.

Answer (score 0):

We can show that we always need an even number of odd primes to satisfy this condition.So the number N has to be of the form 4k+3 for some positive integer k or 4q for some positive integer q.Now if we check for T(99) and t(100).99 falls into the category of 4k+3 and 100 of 4q.Now as we know that they are consecutive integers try to show that whenever 4k+3 and 4q are consecutive integers such that 4q-1=4k+3.Then the number of ways of arranging 4q are more.First you can take examples like t(7) and t(8). and when you solve you will find that the number of arrangements of subsets are more in t(8).and then by induction you can show this is true for all t(n).so we get t(99)

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.